# Unable to update initial state in real time using useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

First of all I apolizize if I am not able to explain the issue properly. I am also aware that useState is asynchronous.  I have tried to simply the code as much as possible .
So bascially, in the code below I have a method handleSubCatChange ,that runs on onChange event. Whenever a checkbox is seleted the subs:[]  in the initial state needs to be populated by the value from the checkbox. The handleSubCatChange  methods checks if the elements of subarray are already in selectedValues .

I have three console.logs , if I click all the three checkboxes one by one  the last one console.log('0002'), shows that the selectedValues array is updated rightaway.

The console.log('000'),  displays empty selectedValues state on the first click and on clicking the second checkbox, logs the first checkbox values , that is apple and when the third check box is clicked the second check box value which is banana is logged. The third  console.log('0001') is even slower, only after all the checkboxes are clicked it displays the first one that is apple in it's array.
I have also tried to use the JSON.stringify, the results are slightly different . {JSON.stringify(selectedValues)}, udpates in real time but {JSON.stringify(values.subs)}  only displays first two elements apple and banana when all three checkboxes have been clicked.

I have lot more properties in my initialstate but for simplicity I have only mentioned title and subs. The check boxes are part of a form element so I need to update the subs:[] in real time so that I I can submit the form with other values . I have tried useEffect but no luck. Please help.

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';

const initialState={ title:'glasses', subs:[],    }

const subarray=['apple','banana','orange']

const ProductCreate=()=>{

const [values,setValues]=useState(initialState); const[selectedValues,setSelectedValues]=useState([]);

useEffect(()=>{
    },[selectedValues])

const handleSubCatChange=(checkedName)=>{

if(selectedValues.includes(checkedName)){
    setSelectedValues(selectedValues.filter((c)=> c!=(checkedName)))
}
  else{ 
    setSelectedValues([...selectedValues,checkedName])
}
    setValues({...values,subs:selectedValues}) 
console.log('0000',selectedValues); console.log('0001',values.subs);}     
    )}
return( <>
 
{JSON.stringify(values.subs)}
{JSON.stringify(selectedValues)}


{subarray.map((s)=>
 <div key={index} >
  {console.log('0002',selectedValues)}
     <input type="checkbox" 
     value={s} 
     onChange={()=>handleSubCatChange(s)}
     />
 </div>
}
</>     )
}
```

Comment: Check out my answer.

Comment: @ Zunayed Shahriar ..I just need to fill property subs;[] array in my initial state, on clicking the checkboxes . So basically when I click first checkbox it should add 'apple' in the array and so on..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want `values` state to be synchronized with `selectedValues` state, then use `useEffect` hook properly.

Use `handleSubCatChange` function only to change state of `selectedValues`.

```
const handleSubCatChange = (checkedName) => {
    if (selectedValues.includes(checkedName)) {
      setSelectedValues(selectedValues.filter((c) => c !== checkedName));
    } else {
      setSelectedValues([...selectedValues, checkedName]);
    }
  };
```

And use `useEffect` hook to change the `values` state only when `selectedValues` state is changed.

```
useEffect(() => {
    setValues({ ...values, subs: selectedValues });
    console.log("0000", selectedValues);
    console.log("0001", values.subs);
  }, [selectedValues]);
```

Working demo at [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-fermat-s7b5u?file=/src/App.jsx).

**Edit:**

To add initial values during `selectedValues` initialization. Change as:

```
const [selectedValues, setSelectedValues] = useState(['banana']);
```

Add `checked` into input to preselect checkboxes.

```
checked={selectedValues.includes(s)}
```

Look at the demo carefully.

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you taking the time to help me resolve the issue!!! :)